# How to Check if a Session Variable Exists using Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to check if a session variable exists using the following line:

```
if (@Session["LoginAttempts"]!=null && (int)@Session["LoginAttempts"] > 3 && dto.Captcha.length == 0)
{

}
```

I get incorrect syntax message at `!=null`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to lose the '@' before `Session` and have it before the `if`, I suppose.

Comment: I cannot do this, because `&& dto.Captcha.length == 0` is javascript.

Comment: The fact that you are mixing client and server side logic should have been something you included in the question as it makes a _big_ difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting the Razor variables into a script block:

```
@{
    var loginAttemptsExceeded = ((int)Session["LoginAttempts"] > 3).ToString().ToLower();
}
```

Then in your JavaScript:

```
var loginAttemptsExceeded = @loginAttemptsExceeded;

if (loginAttemptsExceeded && dto.Captcha.length === 0)
{
    ....
}
```

But what you should be doing is returning a strongly typed `ViewModel` for the view that contains the information you need for the view.

Comment: I updated my answer. You have to `ToString().ToLower()` the `loginAttemptsExceeded` so the JS can read the value as a valid JS bool.